# Methods doOnComplete, doOnTerminate or doOnError aren't called

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have the following situation: I need to get data from db. When I try to get in in UI thread (here's the way how I do it):

```
List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();

for (MovieEntity movie:movieDao.getFavorites()){
    movies.add(getMovie(movie));
}
mView.onMoviesLoaded(movies);
```

Everything works correct

But when I do it in rx:

```
mCompositeDisposable.add(movieDao.getFavorites()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> mView.showLoadingIndicator(true))
                .doOnError(throwable -> {
                    mView.showLoadingIndicator(false);
                    mView.showEmptyState(true);
                })
                .doOnTerminate(() -> mView.showLoadingIndicator(false))
                .doOnComplete(()->mView.showLoadingIndicator(false))
                .flatMapIterable(listObservable -> listObservable)
                .map(this::getMovie)
                .toList()
                .subscribe(list -> {
                    if (list.isEmpty()) {
                        mView.showEmptyState(true);
                    } else {
                        mView.onMoviesLoaded(list);
                    }
                })
        );
```

I have loading indicator all the time. I can't understand, why it happens, as I added `showLoadingIndicator(false)` for all cases (Error and Success cases). So, why it doesn't move away and data isn't showed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`movieDao.getFavorites()` is an infinite stream. Using `.toList()` on an infinite stream does not make sense, because `.toList()` does not emit until the source stream completes.

There are two options:

1. Make your source finite

Make `movieDao.getFavorites()` return a `Single<List<MovieEntity>>` instead of `Observable<List<MovieEntity>>`

or simply put `.take(1)` after the source.

```
mCompositeDisposable.add(movieDao.getFavorites()
                .take(1) // This will terminate the stream after it emits first item.
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                ...
```

2. Or, don't use `.toList()`.

Keep your infinite stream and keep listening to the database change.

```
mCompositeDisposable.add(movieDao.getFavorites()
                .map(movieEntities -> movieEntities.stream().map(this::getMovie).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(list -> {
                    if (list.isEmpty()) {
                        mView.showEmptyState(true);
                    } else {
                        mView.onMoviesLoaded(list);
                    }
                })
        );
```